# Needs to store sitecore (10.0) user login attempt in custom database

Tags: identity-server, logging

We have an ask that we need to login user each login attempt to sitecore. We are able to do that for success scenario but for failure its not done.

If we are not using IdentityServer login, but Sitecore basic login mechanism then by having custom processor for `Sitecore.Pipelines.LoggingIn.CheckClientUser` able do that task successfully.

But if have middleware as IdentityServer then not able to track failure case, as code written under these pipeline don't executes, i have tried each processor of `<owin.cookieAuthentication.signIn>` pipeline but nothing worked.

Any idea how we can achieve it?

Comment: If you use a middleware, you will be redirected to an external system to do your login. If this system does not have an option to log failed requests you cannot access that. Depending on the external system you might or might not be able to access that information.